# SELECT AND echo rows with same ID from 4 SQLite Tables with one query

Tags: php, sqlite

I am trying to select data with same id from four tables using PHP.

Here is the PHP SELECT query:

```
$logId = $_SESSION['log_id'];
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT toexapp.*,toff.*,tolba.*,toibs.*
    FROM toexapp, toff, tolba, toibs
    WHERE toexapp.post_id = ? AND toff.post_id = ? AND tolba.post_id = ? AND toibs.post_id = ?");
$sql->bindParam(1, $logId, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
$sql->bindParam(2, $logId, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
$sql->bindParam(3, $logId, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
$sql->bindParam(4, $logId, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
$result = $sql->execute();

while ($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) 
{
    $req_id = $row['req_id'];
    $req_title = $row['req_title'];
    $min_order = $row['min_order'];
    $poi = $row['poi'];
    $pay_method = $row['pay_method'];
    $req_brief = $row['req_brief'];
    $post_id = $row['post_id'];
    $_SESSION['post_id'] = $post_id;
    $_SESSION['req_id'] = $req_id;
    $towho = $row['towho'];
    $commodityimg = $row['commodityimg'];

    echo '<form action="deletepost.php" method="post" enctype="nultipart/form-data">
    <div class="postSlate">
                            <input style="display: none" type="submit" name="deletepost" id="deletepost" value="Delete">
                        <label for="deletepost"><i class="typcn typcn-delete clsup2"></i></label>
                            <input type="text" style="display: none" name="reqid" class="reqid" value="'.$req_id.'">
                        </form>
                <ul class="slateDetails"><a href="userprofile.php?userid='.$post_id.'"><li><img class="exdetails" src="'.$profimages.'"></li><li>'.$cname.'</li></a></ul>
                <div class="slateImg"><img src="'.$commodityimg.'"></div>
                <div class="slateTitle extitle"><p>'.$req_title.'</p></div>
                <div class="slateBrief"><p>'.$req_brief.'</p></div>
                <div class="slateBtn">
                </div>
                </div>';
}
```

I have four tables from which I one to `SELECT FROM WHERE post_id = $logID` in one query but my current query currently `echo` nothing with no errors. How can I solve this?

Comment: echo nothing with no errors suggests that your query returns 0 rows. Are you sure there is at least one row with the given post_id in each of the four tables?

Comment: Yes 100% sure. Is my query correct?

Comment: I tried your query on a mock database and it worked when there was exactly 1 row with the given post_id in each row. Try your query from the console with sqlite3. If it works in the console, php code is at fault. If it doesn't work in the console, your database is at fault.